# Сносил PHP с Ubuntu. Так вышло, что удалилась папка var/lib/php

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Сейчас ставлю phpmyadmin, на странице логгина выскакивает предупреждение, что папки var/lib/php/sessions нет, зашёл, чекнул. После переустановки появилась папка var/lib/php а session нет

Answer (score 1):

Так создайте эту папку под root и задайте права 1733 для папки

```
sudo su

mkdir /var/lib/php/sessions

chmod 1733 /var/lib/php/sessions
```